# Angular 2 How to selectively save state while routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am creating a search page that allows users to navigate to the specific record and when they return to the search page, their search criteria are still populated.  I tried using this https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx and it worked great.

The issue is, there are other pages I navigate to that have filters based on request params, that are also saving the previous state, not the new one, for example, say i navigate to /page?type=foo and it displays 10 results, then I navigate to /page?type=bar, it should show 5 results, but is still showing the 10 results from foo...ie: it's also remembering it's previous state.

So my question is, How can I selectively control when state is saved. Ideally, I want to save state on the search screen only when coming from the details page, not when navigating to search from the main page.

Thanks

-Todd

Comment: you can pass a params in the route link

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit?  what would I do with the param passed into the routeLink, how do I pass it?  sorry, it's just not really clear to me

Answer (score 1):

When comming from detail page and main page

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                    let detailPage = params[ 'detailPage' ];
                    if (detailPage) {
                          // do something
                     }
            });
```

and in detail component

```
let link = ['pathScreen',{ detailPage : true }];
this.router.navigate(link)
```

and in main Page

```
 let link = ['pathScreen'];
 this.router.navigate(link)
```

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try...one other question, what is 'pathScreen'?

Comment: it is a  example path, you put there you path to component search screen